# HIDictionaryWindowShow usage in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, macos-carbon

How do you invoke `HIDictionaryWindowShow` in Swift? I try this:

```
import Carbon

if let text = _dictionaryText, let range = _dictionaryRange
{
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName("Baskerville", 16, nil);
    let point = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0);
    var trns = CGAffineTransform();
    HIDictionaryWindowShow(nil, text, range, font, point, false, &trns);
}
```

But getting error

> Cannot invoke 'HIDictionaryWindowShow' with an argument list of type
>   '(nil, String, CFRange, CTFont!, CGPoint, Bool, CGAffineTransform)'

Not seeing the wrong argument here. First and last argument should be allowed to be `nil` but [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/HIDictionaryWindowShow) say that `NULL` is Ok as the first argument which is `nil` in Swift or is it? As there is no `NULL` in Swift what do I need to specify instead of it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the Swift code, but you can probably work from the following untested objective-c code.  Note that showDefinitionForAttributedString was added to replace HIDictionaryWindowShow which is, as you know, a carbon function and won't be supported forever.

```
    [self.view showDefinitionForAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text] atPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0)];
```

EDIT:

In looking further the second argument is not correct in your example.   Carbon lib does not understand `String`, it wants `CFTypeRef`.